# dimple.js/d3.js Toggle between Normal and log scale

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I figured out from looking at the dimple.js code that by setting the useLog property of an axis, i can toggle between log and normal scaling.

http://jsbin.com/fifoqe/1/edit

Two problems with the above code:

1. When i click the 'toggle log' checkbox, nothing happens UNLESS i then click on a legend item
2. When the log scale is displayed, i would still like the series to 'fill' the chart, but that is not the case as the log axis goes from 0 - 1000, despite the fact that i set the minOverride to 65.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a line in your code which refers to a non-existent variable:

```
primYAxis.logBase = 2;
```

if you change that to refer to the y axis:

```
yAxis.logBase = 2;
```

it seems to behave as you intend

http://jsbin.com/fiqeru/2/edit?js,output